Reactivate inactive PowerPages Site if not owner/creator
How can an Admin user that is not the Creator reactivate an inactive Site in PowerPages (after deployment / import through a Solution)?
So far it seems the only way to reactivate a Site is by going through the portal. But as an Admin user that is not the creator the "Inactive sites" tab remains empty and the reactivate button cannot be clicked.
It seems to be only visible to the Creator user. Unfortunately the Creator user does not have permission to create app registrations in Azure AD (and due to company policy will probably never get it) and therefor cannot perform the reactivation themselves.
What is the most promising way forward for this problem? I somehow can't believe this can't be done by an Admin user.

